# I'm excited about a personal project, should I do it in PHP or Rails ( but I have to learn Rails first )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project

I started learning Rails only a few days ago, but in the mean time I became very excited about a personal project. The project is quite hefty and would require several months to complete.
Right now, I can't wait to start doing that project but I'm a bit reluctant in writing it in PHP.

I've been working in PHP for a little more than a year now and I can find my way around it fairly well. Ruby on Rails however is a mystery to me and I will probably need two or three weeks before I can even start coding poorly in Rails.

So my question is, should I start my project in PHP and postpone my Rails studying or should I first get the basics of Rails and do the project in Rails.

The project consists of dealing with a lot of data taken from google search.

This sounds like a stupid question, I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the exact same situation recently, and I went with Rails. I'd definitely recommend it. It's worth putting in some effort to learn Ruby first - I read [Why's (Poignant) Guide](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) and that set me up well. Also, get [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails) - it's a great introduction. If you have the time, you could learn enough to get started in a week or two.

If you can spare the time to go through Why's Guide and AWDwR before you get started properly then do. Otherwise, maybe PHP would be a better choice. Also, if you're worried that your excitement about the project will wane if you don't get started on it soon, go with PHP. You can always rewrite it in Rails!

Answer (score 2):

A personal project that you are excited about sounds like a perfect opportunity for you to learn Rails.

There is a bit of a learning curve, but the time spent will be well worth it. Spend lots of time watching [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com), try things out, and have fun!

Comment: Railscasts are good, but they're not great for someone just starting out. I'd say move onto them once you've finished WPGtR and AWDwR.

Answer (score 1):

Not a stupid question.

As you will see in a number of other answers to a number of other questions around here:

**Never pass up the opportunity to learn something new.**

I say try it in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

do it in rails - there's a good and up-to-date ebook [here](http://railstutorial.org/book) that will help you learn: www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: That is the tutorial I'm following at the moment actually.